# How to iterate through line and check needed part?

Tags: bash, unix

I have this line

```
Username:x:120:101:somethingsomething
```

and I need to get the '101' part after the third ':', how can I do that?
do I use grep or sed?

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d':' -f4 /etc/passwd
```

awk, only with string:

```
mstr="Username:x:120:101:somethingsomething"; awk -F: '{print $4}' <<< "$mstr"
```

Comment: `cut` accepts filenames, no need for `cat`